# Best way to solve $24^{100} \times 1.5^{50} \times 12^{-149}$

Tags: exponentiation

I think I could solve this but I would like to know the best way to do it with the least amount of calculations

Comment: **HINT**: Express $24$ and $12$ as a product of their prime factors and express $1.5$ as $\frac{3}{2}$ then use standard laws of indices to simplify.

Comment: thanks i didn't think about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ 24^{100} \times 1.5^{50} \times 12^{-149} = (3\cdot 2^3)^{100} \times (3\cdot 2^{-1})^{50} \times (3 \cdot 2^2)^{-149} \\ =  3^{100} \cdot 2^{300}\cdot 3^{50}\cdot 2^{-50}\cdot 2^{-298}\cdot 3^{-149} = ...$$

You can add exponents to get the final answer

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Mufasa in comments, expand in powers of $2$ and $3$:
$$
\overbrace{2^{300}3^{100}}^{24^{100}}\overbrace{3^{50}2^{-50}}^{1.5^{50}}\overbrace{2^{-298}3^{-149}}^{12^{-149}}=3\cdot2^{-48}
$$
We can also reduce computation with $2^{-48}=\left(\left(\left(\left(\frac18\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2\right)^2$